# Logs complaining "extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s

I'm adding an Ingress as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cheddar
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cheddar.213.215.191.78.nip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: cheddar
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

but the logs complain:

```
W0205 15:14:07.482439       1 warnings.go:67] extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
time="2021-02-05T15:14:07Z" level=info msg="Updated ingress status" namespace=default ingress=cheddar
W0205 15:18:19.104225       1 warnings.go:67] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 IngressClass is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 IngressClassList
```

Why? What's the correct yaml to use?
I'm currently on microk8s 1.20

Comment: Did you created or updated the ingress in the new cluster? i ran into the issues once, when i was upgrading the cluster, i had to delete the resource and recreate. It couldn't see any change, when i was applying it again.

Comment: In both servers, I started from scratch but then I deleted and recreated ingress controller

Comment: Despite the warning messages, can you confirm that the Ingress is in fact not working?

Comment: On the contrary: the Ingress IS working. Simply I wanted to use the proper definition to avoid cluttering the logs.

Comment: For reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I have analyzed you issue and came to the following conclusions:

1. The Ingress will work and these Warnings you see are just to inform you about the available api versioning. You don't have to worry about this. I've seen the same Warnings:

---

```
@microk8s:~$ kubectl describe ing
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
```

2. As for the "why" this is happening even when you use `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1`, I have found the [following explanation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94761#issuecomment-691982480):

> This is working as expected. When you create an ingress object, it can
> be read via any version (the server handles converting into the
> requested version). `kubectl get ingress` is an ambiguous request,
> since it does not indicate what version is desired to be read.
>
> When an ambiguous request is made, kubectl searches the discovery docs
> returned by the server to find the first group/version that contains
> the specified resource.
>
> For compatibility reasons, `extensions/v1beta1` has historically been
> preferred over all other api versions. Now that ingress is the only
> resource remaining in that group, and is deprecated and has a GA
> replacement, 1.20 will drop it in priority so that `kubectl get ingress` would read from `networking.k8s.io/v1`, but a 1.19 server
> will still follow the historical priority.
>
> If you want to read a specific version, you can qualify the get
> request (like `kubectl get ingresses.v1.networking.k8s.io` ...) or can
> pass in a manifest file to request the same version specified in the
> file (`kubectl get -f ing.yaml -o yaml`)

Long story short: despite the fact of using the proper `apiVersion`, the deprecated one is still being seen as the the default one and thus generating the Warning you experience.

I also see that [changes are still being made](https://github.com/concourse/concourse-chart/issues/204) recently so I assume that it is still being worked on.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your answer before. I accepted as it in fact explains the questions. The only remaining doubt is that I'm already using 1.20...

Comment: I have created the ingress service with the ingress pod in runnning state. I cannot see the loadbalancer for some reason. It is just not getting created.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was unable to update the k8s cluster which was subscribed to release channel.
One of the reasons for this log warning generation is the ClusterRole definition of external-dns. The external-dns keep querying the ingresses in k8s cluster as per the rules defined in the Cluster role

```
- apiGroups: ["extensions", "networking.k8s.io"]
  resources: ["ingresses"] 
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
```

Found in the helm chart in [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/charts/external-dns/templates/clusterrole.yaml#L26)

It queries the old extensions of ingress as well which keeps on generating those logs. Please update the cert-manager.