# how to use ALB Ingress with api networking.k8s.io/v1 in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

Previously I was using the `extensions/v1beta1` api to create ALB on Amazon EKS. After upgrading the EKS to `v1.19` I started getting warnings:

```
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
```

So I started to update my ingress configuration accordingly and deployed the ALB but the ALB is not launching in AWS and also not getting the ALB address.

Ingress configuration -->

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "pub-dev-alb"
  namespace: "dev-env"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip

spec:
  rules:
  - host: "dev.test.net"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: "dev-test-tg"
            port:
              number: 80
```

Node port configuration -->

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "dev-test-tg"
  namespace: "dev-env"
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3001
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: "dev-test-server"
```

Results --->

[image]

Used [this documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-alb-ingress-controller-setup/) to create ALB ingress controller.

Could anyone help me on here?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. This is just a warning so all my resources run as expected with extensions/v1beta1 on AWS EKS with Kubernetes 1.19 but I'd like to know what's the recommended way to upgrade to avoid problems when we get to 1.22.

Answer (score 2):

Your ingress should work fine even if you use newest Ingress. The warnings you see indicate that a new version of the API is available. You don't have to worry about it.

Here is the [explanation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94761) why this warning occurs, even if you you use `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1`:

> This is working as expected. When you create an ingress object, it can be read via any version (the server handles converting into the requested version).  `kubectl get ingress`  is an ambiguous request, since it does not indicate what version is desired to be read.
>
> When an ambiguous request is made, kubectl searches the discovery docs returned by the server to find the first group/version that contains the specified resource.
>
> For compatibility reasons,  `extensions/v1beta1`  has historically been preferred over all other api versions. Now that ingress is the only resource remaining in that group, and is deprecated and has a GA replacement, 1.20 will drop it in priority so that  `kubectl get ingress`  would read from  `networking.k8s.io/v1`, but a 1.19 server will still follow the historical priority.
>
> If you want to read a specific version, you can qualify the get request (like  `kubectl get ingresses.v1.networking.k8s.io`  ...) or can pass in a manifest file to request the same version specified in the file (`kubectl get -f ing.yaml -o yaml`)

You can also see a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080909).